# How to add a new line in XWPFDocument in java?

Tags: java, document, xwpf

I wanted to create a line break in  XWPFDocument paragraph, I tried the below code, but its not working.

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" we strive hard to " +
     "provide quality tutorials for self-learning " +
     "purpose in the domains of Academics, Information " +
     "Technology, Management and Computer Programming
     Languages.");

  document.write(out);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the text and use 
`run.addBreak();`
to add a break in between

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `newline` character: `\n`.